# Filling in last known value in MySQL recordset output when no data available

Tags: php, mysql

Consider the following three tables:

```
daterange     stocks                               companies
-----------   ----------------------------------   ----------------
_date         stock_id  nyse_date   open   close   stock_id  name
-----------   ----------------------------------   ----------------
2011-03-11    1         2011-03-11  40.50  40.60   1         Alcoa
2011-03-12    1         2011-03-14  40.62  41.04   2         Apple
2011-03-13    1         2011-03-15  41.00  41.20   .           .
2011-03-14    1         2011-03-16  41.15  42.00   .           .
2011-03-15    1         2011-03-18  41.50  41.80   100       Xerox
2011-03-16
2011-03-17
2011-03-18
```

`daterange` contains a continuous set of dates between march 11st and september 1st, 2011. Over the same period, `stocks` contains the `open` and `close` pricing information for 100 stocks. The stocks / companies are in `companies`.

During the weekend, `2011-03-12` and `2011-03-13` and during holidays (for example, `2011-03-17`), no pricing information is available.

What I need is a list with `open` and `close` pricing information for *each of the dates in `daterange`*. Whenever there is a `_date` in `daterange` for which there is no pricing information in `stocks`, the last known pricing information has to be filled in.

So for Alcoa (`stock_id 1`), given the `daterange` dates given, the output would have to be (* = taken from last know value):

```
stock_id _date       open   close 
---------------------------------
1        2011-03-11  40.50  40.60
1        2011-03-12  40.50  40.60 *
1        2011-03-13  40.50  40.60 *
1        2011-03-14  40.62  41.04
1        2011-03-15  41.00  41.20
1        2011-03-16  41.15  42.00
1        2011-03-17  41.15  42.00 *
1        2011-03-18  41.50  41.80
```

...in reality followed by all the dates up to september 1st, and then continuing with `stock_id` 2 (`open` and `close` not given in example)

```
2        2011-03-11  10.11  10.15
2        2011-03-12  10.11  10.15 * 
2        2011-03-13  10.11  10.15 *
2        2011-03-14  10.20  10.24
.        .
.        .
```

Would this be possible to do in MySQL? Alternatively, I could use PHP to download the dates from `daterange` and loop through `stocks`, filling in whenever there is no entry for a specific date. But I guess MySQL would be a lot faster.

Any help is appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried this out and it seems to get what you need.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 1 AS Stock_id, D._date, 
       (SELECT S2.Open From Stocks S2
        WHERE S2.Stock_id=1
          AND S2.nyse_date < DATE_ADD(D._date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
        ORDER BY S2.nyse_date DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS open,
       (SELECT S3.Close From Stocks S3
        WHERE S3.Stock_id=1
          AND S3.nyse_date < DATE_ADD(D._date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) 
        ORDER BY S3.nyse_date DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS close
FROM daterange D LEFT JOIN stocks S1 ON D._date=S1.nyse_date
ORDER BY D._date ;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but since I'm not that advanced in SQL - is this MySQL syntax? I don't know how to interpret @TargetStockID...

Comment: @Pr0no, Sorry, I had SQL Server on my mind.  I changed the syntax to mySQL.  The `@TargetStockID` was a parameter for whichever stock_id you were looking for.  It is usually passed from your calling code.  However, I know many people simply concatenate strings together to build their SQL. (Note that I substituted '1' for the stock_id wherever I had `@TargetStockID`.)

Comment: it works in the sense that if there is no stock data, it correctly takes the values of the previous day. It does not work in the sense that in the recordset output, there are 100 records for each date on which there is stock data available. I have updated your post with example output to show you what I mean. Do you have any idea?

Comment: @Pr0no, I added the `DISTINCT` statement in the first line.  I've tried it out against your sample data and get one result per day with the "blank" days being filled in from the most recent info available.